# Windows Mobile Sockets SSL Communication library

Tags: c++, sockets, windows-mobile, ssl

I have a Win32 application that uses boost::asio and openssl library but it seems that they are not supported under WM, am I correct?
Can anyone suggest WM API/library for WM Sockets, I need to connect to a server through SSL connection.
Is the only option for me WinSocks + OpenSSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know of any other libraries for WM that provide socket and ssl connectivity, I can confirm that sockets and OpenSSL do work fine on WM5 and above devices. You have to jump through a few hoops to get openssl built for wm5 and ARM, as there are some parts of the c runtime missing, these are plugged with [this](http://github.com/mauricek/wcecompat)

Also [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg54849.html) post was useful, as you have to build it on the command line, rather than in visual studio.